# Bucket script java api in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I made elasticsearch query that get each oid name and it's count divided by 1000. ( the number(1000) can be changed)

> ```
>     "aggregations" : {
>         "agg_oid" : {
>           "terms" : {
>             "field" : "oid",
>             "order" : {
>               "_count" : "desc"
>             }
>           },
>           "aggregations" : {
>               "agg_values" : {
>                   "bucket_script": {
>                         "buckets_path": {
>                           "count": "_count"
>                         },
>                         "script": "count / 1000"
>                     }
>               }
>           }
>         }
>       }
> ```

It works well, and tried to make it with java api (currently using jest).

```
AggregationBuilders
    .terms( "agg_oid")
    .field( "oid")
    .subAggregation(
        AggregationBuilders
             // bucket script and path for count
    );
```

How to implement of 'bucket_script' in java? If not, is there any way to query aggregation's count with caculating in java api?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
Map<String, String> bucketsPathsMap = new HashMap<>();
bucketsPathsMap.put("count", "_count");
Script script = new Script("count / 1000");

BucketScriptPipelineAggregationBuilder bs = PipelineAggregatorBuilders
    .bucketScript("agg_values", bucketsPathsMap, script);

TermsAggregationBuilder oid = AggregationBuilders.terms("agg_oid")
    .field("oid")
    .order(InternalOrder.COUNT_DESC).
    subAggregation(bs);
```